# I do have a difference between emulator and android studio design there is about 10 sp or some staff like that

Tags: android, emulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXKhd.png)

Hi All I do have a difference between emulator in android studio and design page in the same android studio , there is the same phone but a little bit different size , see attached and please advice what can I do to fix it.

Comment: Attach `.xml` code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIQry.png)

The only action which had to be done to fix this issue is to set up "Show System UI"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @gambit7991 You should also share the design XML you created